# Compatible Microsoft EDGE version for latest selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, microsoft-edge

Currently I'm using:

```
<selenium.version>4.0.0-alpha-5</selenium.version>
```

for Microsoft EDGE browser version *103.0.1264.62 (64 bit)* and all my automation scripts are working perfectly .
When i'm updating the selenium version with latest one i.e *4.3.0* then scripts are started failing:

```
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'LHT6626355535', ip: '10.98.11.998', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_261'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, ms:edgeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
NAME IS :Validate the Member Details Page Header section First Column Data Validation 2022.07.25.14.13.28.png
java.lang.NullPointerException
REGRESSION_MEMBER_DETAILS_SECTION
File created Screenshots\Results
An exception occured while taking screenshot null
Screenshot Captured
    at com.optum.taskTracker.ui.stepDefinitions.Hooks.tearDown(Hooks.java:282)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal code snippet which can reproduce the issue? I test with selenium server 4.3.0 and Edge version 103.0.1264.71, it works well. But my Java version is newer which is 1.8.0_341. It would be better that you upgrade your Java and Edge to the latest version and test again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally ensure that *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u331](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).

Comment: This is what my issue is .I have already used 4.3.0 and scripts are failing . How to fix it ?

Comment: Hello , 
I'm using the latest version of java
java.version: '1.8.0_261'

Comment: `1.8.0_261` is ancient now try `1.8.0_333`

Comment: This is the only latest version 1.8.0_261 supported in my Org.

Answer (score 0):

Try folowing:-

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
        </dependency
    <!--

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then try this:-

```
String browserName = "EDGE";
//String chromeProfilePath = prop.getProperty("ChromeCookies"); //Use cookies

if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        //options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
        //options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + chromeProfilePath);
        //options.addArguments("--headless");
        //options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));    
        contr0l = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
else if (browserName.equals("Edge")) {
    WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
    contr0l = new EdgeDriver();
}
else if (browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
    WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
    contr0l = new FirefoxDriver();
}
else if (browserName.equals("Safari")) {
    WebDriverManager.safaridriver().setup();
    contr0l = new SafariDriver();
}
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but still not working for me .
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
      driver = new EdgeDriver();
      System.out.println("APP URL :"+app_url);
      driver.get(app_url);
Browser gets launched but failed to print "APP URL" thats mean code not reaching to driver.get(app_url)